# Pandas Dataframe Mutli index sorting by level and column value

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
                         value
           Id              
2014-03-13 1          -3
           2          -6
           3          -3.2
           4          -3.1
           5          -5
2014-03-14 1          -3.4
           2          -6.2
           3          -3.2
           4          -3.2
           5          -5.9
```

which is basically a groupby object with two levels of multi-index.

I want to sort it in ascending order according to the `value` column, but keeping the level 0 (dates) untouched so that the result should look like this:

```
                         value
           Id              
2014-03-13 2          -6
           5          -5
           3          -3.2
           4          -3.1
           1          -3
2014-03-14 2          -6.2
           5          -5.9
           1          -3.4
           3          -3.2
           4          -3.2
```

Here is the code to generate the initial data:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = [pd.to_datetime('2014-03-13', format='%Y-%m-%d'), pd.to_datetime('2014-03-13', format='%Y-%m-%d'), pd.to_datetime('2014-03-13', format='%Y-%m-%d'), pd.to_datetime('2014-03-13', format='%Y-%m-%d'),
         pd.to_datetime('2014-03-13', format='%Y-%m-%d'),pd.to_datetime('2014-03-14', format='%Y-%m-%d'), pd.to_datetime('2014-03-14', format='%Y-%m-%d'), pd.to_datetime('2014-03-14', format='%Y-%m-%d'), 
         pd.to_datetime('2014-03-14', format='%Y-%m-%d'), pd.to_datetime('2014-03-14', format='%Y-%m-%d')]

values = [-3,-6,-3.2,-3.1,-5,-3.4,-6.2,-3.2,-3.2,-5.9]
Ids = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': pd.Series(Ids, index=dates),
                   'value': pd.Series(values, index=dates)})

df = df.groupby([df.index,'Id']).sum()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me works [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) + [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.reset_index() \
       .sort_values(['level_0','value']) \
       .set_index(['level_0','Id']) \
       .rename_axis([None, 'Id'])
print (df)
               value
           Id       
2014-03-13 2    -6.0
           5    -5.0
           3    -3.2
           4    -3.1
           1    -3.0
2014-03-14 2    -6.2
           5    -5.9
           1    -3.4
           3    -3.2
           4    -3.2
```

Another solution with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) + [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.sort_values('value')
       .swaplevel(0,1)
       .sort_index(level=1, sort_remaining=False)
       .swaplevel(0,1)
print (df)
               value
           Id       
2014-03-13 2    -6.0
           5    -5.0
           3    -3.2
           4    -3.1
           1    -3.0
2014-03-14 2    -6.2
           5    -5.9
           1    -3.4
           3    -3.2
           4    -3.2
```

---

Swap levels is necessary because:

```
print (df.sort_values('value').sort_index(level=0, sort_remaining=False))
               value
           Id       
2014-03-13 1    -3.0
           2    -6.0
           3    -3.2
           4    -3.1
           5    -5.0
2014-03-14 1    -3.4
           2    -6.2
           3    -3.2
           4    -3.2
           5    -5.9
```

---

For pandas `0.23.0` is possible sort [columns and index levels together](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#sorting-by-a-combination-of-columns-and-index-levels):

```
df.index.names = ['level1','level2']
print (df.sort_values(['level1','value']))
                   value
level1     level2       
2014-03-13 2        -6.0
           5        -5.0
           3        -3.2
           4        -3.1
           1        -3.0
2014-03-14 2        -6.2
           5        -5.9
           1        -3.4
           3        -3.2
           4        -3.2
```

Comment: this solution assumes that outer level is "sortable", is there a way to sort inner level of a multiindex respecting outer level?
My outer level is consists of strings and I do not want to sort outer level alphabetically.

Comment: Hard question without data. But maybe need something like `df = df.reset_index().groupby('level_0', sort=False).apply(lambda x : x.sort_values('level_1')).set_index(['level_1'], append=True)` should working. If not, can you add some data?

Comment: Thank you, Sir. That solves the issue, but has two unexpected consequences... it would be great if you could help me understand how come (1) index becomes a part of the table (2) one if the columns gets duplicated  after running `df.reset_index().groupby('level_0', sort=False).apply(lambda x : x.sort_values('level_1'))`

here is the [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbGGo.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7h8h.png). The general structure of the data frame is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45987198/grouped-bar-chart-how-to-make-sns-respect-order-of-rows)

Comment: I obviously solved those issues by dropping the columns, I am just trying to figure out what happens behind the scene.

Comment: Yoi can try add parameter `group_keys=False` to groupby. Not sure if it working, bwcause now on phone only.

Comment: Remove first level is possible double reset_index like `.reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()` and reason why is it duplicayed in my opinion is becasue not implemented nice or bug.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, a simultaneous sort on both index and column isn't possible, but a simple workaround would be the following:

```
df = df.reset_index().sort_values(by = ['level_0','values']).set_index(['level_0','Id'])
```

...and if you need to get rid of the 'level_0' index label:

```
df.index.names = [None, 'Id']
```

**Setup:**

```
import pandas as pd
import io

c = io.StringIO(u'''
                Id      value
2014-03-13      1       -3
2014-03-13      2       -6
2014-03-13      3       -3.2                                                                                                                      2014-03-13      4       -3.1
2014-03-13      5       -5
2014-03-14      1       -3.4
2014-03-14      2       -6.2
2014-03-14      3       -3.2
2014-03-14      4       -3.2
2014-03-14      5       -5.9
''')

df = pd.read_csv(c, delim_whitespace = True)
df = df.groupby([df.index,'Id']).max()
```

**Initial df:**

```
               value
           Id
2014-03-13 1    -3.0
           2    -6.0
           3    -3.2
           4    -3.1
           5    -5.0
2014-03-14 1    -3.4
           2    -6.2
           3    -3.2
           4    -3.2
           5    -5.9
```

**Ouput:**

```
               value
           Id
2014-03-13 2    -6.0
           5    -5.0
           3    -3.2
           4    -3.1
           1    -3.0
2014-03-14 2    -6.2
           5    -5.9
           1    -3.4
           3    -3.2
           4    -3.2
```

Comment: This does not work, I get the same as my input data!

Comment: Right, in my setup I included a `date` column, which I now realize you don't have.  Working on it.

Comment: Since my index including the dates does not have name, it will end up as `level_0`. But even replacing `date` by `level_0` does not change anything.

Comment: @JefeBelfort - I ran this and it worked perfectly.  Used `level_0` and got values sorted as requested.

Comment: I get an error at line 5: `pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data.`

Comment: Could be an extra space somewhere that is throwing the `delim_whitespace`.  Everything I posted gets both the exact dataframe you started with and the exact output you're looking fo.

Comment: Ok I have added the input data in the question, but I swear that applying your answer does not change the data!

Comment: I just ran my code based on how you setup your initial `df` and my code works the same.  Are you sure you're setting `df = df...`?

Comment: Ok I found the issue: you should have written `.sort_values(by = ['level_0','value'])` instead of `.sort_values(by = ['level_0','Id'])` (cf: answer below)

Comment: Ugh, you're right.  My bad.  My code on my console had that, my answer didn't.  Wouldn't mind an up-vote for the effort.

Comment: Damn, sorry for that, I would have liked you to be rewarded for your effort