# Grouped bar chart -- how to make sns respect order of rows?

Tags: seaborn

I have a multilevel data frame, sorted by values on level=1

[image: my data]

I want to make a grouped bar plot. When I do

```
ax = sns.barplot(ax=ax, x="level0", y="values",
             hue="level1", data=data)
```

Sns decides to sort index by level1.

[image: result]

Is there a way to make sns respect the order of rows when making grouped bar plots?

Comment: [`seaborn.barplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) has arguments `order` and `hue_order`. If you have a problem using them, please provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment from @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, you can use the `order` and `hue_order` parameters to control in which order the bars appear along the x-axis.